# What does "僕は出来れば早く年を取ってしまひたい" mean?

Tags: grammar

From "ビブリア古書堂の事件手帖":

> 僕は出来れば早く年を取ってしまひたい。すこし位腰が曲がったって仕方がない

What I am confused about is the "てしまひたい" part. Is it a grammar point (aside from the "たい"), and what does it indicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ひ in the sentence is [歴史的仮名遣](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%AD%B4%E5%8F%B2%E7%9A%84%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D%E9%81%A3) ([Historical kana orthography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_kana_orthography#General_differences)).

## Japanese

> 語頭以外の「わ・い・う・え・お」の多くが「は・ひ・ふ・へ・ほ」であり、「ゐ・ゑ・を」であるものもある。
>
> > 例：かは（川）　こひ（鯉）　あふ（会う）　まへ（前）　かほ（顔）　あゐ（藍）　こゑ（声）　あを（青）

## English

> The series of kana ha hi fu he ho are used to represent, in some words, the sounds wa, i, u, e, o, respectively.

## Japanese

So しまひたい is しまいたい in modern writing =  しまう (finish/end up) + たい (want to).  Roughly the first sentence means,

- If possible, I'd like to get old sooner.

(Or 出来れば早く can be understood as 出来るだけ早く = as soon as possible.)